# Is there a way via Visual Studio Code to deploy a branch to a Salesforce org?

Tags: deployment, gitlab

Is there a command like "Deploy from SFDX branch to a Salesforce Org" ?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. SFDX is not tied to any particular source/version control tool, so it doesn't know about branches (nor should it). It can only see the folder/file structure of the project directory.

For CI/CD purposes (or even just deploying from your own computer), all you need to do here is:

- Make sure you have a copy of your repository
- Use git/mercurial/svn/whatever to switch to the branch you want to deploy
- Use sfdx to deploy

It's the responsibility of the source/version control tool to adjust the contents of your sfdx project directory to match the state of the "branch" you're in.

Comment: And even though 2GP (second-generattion packaging) [does support "branches"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_use_branches.htm), that's mostly just an extra string that gets added onto the package version for our squishy human brains to read. It isn't tied into any version control system